# Convert image to txt with python

Tags: python-3.x

I have this .py file that should convert images to strings.

img2str.py:

```
from PIL import Image
from pytesseract import image_to_string

image = Image.open('image.png', mode='r')
print(image_to_string(image))
```

I tried:

```
python3 img2str.py
```

I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/linux/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 223, in run_tesseract
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd_args, **subprocess_args())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 729, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1364, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'tesseract': 'tesseract'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "img2str.py", line 4, in <module>
    results = tes.image_to_string(Image.open('image.png'))
  File "/home/linux/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 345, in image_to_string
    }[output_type]()
  File "/home/linux/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 344, in <lambda>
    Output.STRING: lambda: run_and_get_output(*args),
  File "/home/linux/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 253, in run_and_get_output
    run_tesseract(**kwargs)
  File "/home/linux/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 225, in run_tesseract
    raise TesseractNotFoundError()
pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractNotFoundError: tesseract is not installed or it's not in your path
```

Installing tesseract:

```
sudo pip install pytesseract --user
[sudo] heslo pro linux:    
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
ImportError: cannot import name main
```

Another way:
installing commad for the second time and it seems to be installed.

```
pip install pytesseract --user
Requirement already satisfied: pytesseract in ./.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (0.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: Pillow in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from pytesseract) (5.1.0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably missing `tesseract-ocr` from your machine. Check the installation instructions here: https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki

Or on linux, you can just install using apt:

```
sudo apt install tesseract-ocr
sudo apt install libtesseract-dev
```

If these commands don't fix the problem, you'll have to refer to the wiki linked above.